# Classifying non-abelian group(s) of order $18$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Problem: Classify the non-abelian group(s) of order $18$.

I am currently working on the problem above. I think the answer can be $C_{18}$, $D_{18}$, $C_{3} \times C_{3} \times C_{2}$, $S_{3} \times C_{3}$.
Can someone show me what the correct answer is? Thank you.

Comment: Two of those are abelian, You are still missing one group.

Comment: If $D_n$ is the dihedral group, perhaps you mean $D_9$ rather than $D_{18}$.

Comment: Some people denote by $D_n$ the group with $n$ elements, not with $2n$ elements.

Comment: Yes, I mean $D_{18}$ the group with 18 elements As Dietrich said. @egreg

Comment: @DerekHolt Yea I am missing $E_{9}$. So the complete groups should be $D_{18}, S_{3} \times C_{3}\ and\ E_{9}$. Thank you.